# Containerized Angular in Service Fabric

Tags: angular, docker, containers

I'm trying to wrap my head around containerized Angular apps pushed to Service Fabric. Following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-docker-cli) tutorial, I have successfully pulled an image, ran it on my local, and have pushed it to my Service Fabric Container Repo.

My question is this: if I create an Angular application with Docker file and place that in a Docker container, can I "run" the web app from Service Fabric after I push this container to the SF container repo? I have the option to deploy to a web app after the push, but it's not what I was expecting. As it is creating an App Service. Browsing this displays a "good job your service is running" default.html, not my Angular app.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs#create-a-project-zip-file) solution.